# How to launch a TKinter Progress Bar from main

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have code in a method that creates a progress bar:

```
def progress_bar(self, message = None, icon_path = None, icon_name = None, size = 0, file_location = None, interval = 100):
    #size: in bytes of download
    #file_location: location of the download
    #interval: frequency, in ms, of how often to poll the file for progress
    self.find_icon(icon_path, icon_name)
    self.text_label = tk.Label(text = message)
    self.set_colors(self.text_label)
    self.set_colors(self.image_label)
    self.image_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'NSEW')
    self.text_label.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'NSEW')
    self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=(self.xp/3), mode="determinate")
    self.progress.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'NSEW')
    self.progress["value"] = 0
    self.progress["maximum"] = size
    self.auto_resize(1, 3)
    self.progress.start(interval)
    self.after(1, self.check_for_completion(file_location))
    self.mainloop()

def check_for_completion(self, file_location):
    #while (self.progress["value"] < self.progress["maximum"]):
    self.progress["value"] = os.stat(file_location).st_size
    print self.progress["value"]

    if (self.progress["value"] >= self.progress["maximum"]):
        self.text_label = tk.Label(text = message + ": Completed")
        #force a repaint and wait for the user to see it
        self.text_label.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        time.sleep(30)
        self.choice(True)
        self._delete_window
```

and by way of sanity testing, I have a _ _ main _ _ method in the the same script and what I want to do is create a temp file, launch the progress bar and then start putting chars into the temp file.  Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to launch the progress bar in a non blocking way.

I tried playing with python Multiprocessing like this:

```
p = Process(target = frame4.progress_bar, kwargs = kwarrgh)
p.start()
p.join()
```

and got a very angry ;) message saying

```
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

NOTE: The important part of this exercise is to launch the Tkinter window in the background from the main, not the other way around.  I've found a bunch of SO questions on the latter, but not the former.

The answer is not required to be threadsafe, in case there is a multithreading rather than multiprocessing approach that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply keep calling the function `check_for_completion` with `after()` until your process is complete.

```
def check_for_completion(self, file_location):
    ... # your code

    if (self.progress["value"] >= self.progress["maximum"]):
        ... # you code 
    else:             # 'value' is not bigger then maximum so we run the function again.
        self.after(10, lambda: self.check_for_completion(file_location))
```

Please note how i used the after method to call the function with arguments. You should also do it like that on your line:

```
#self.after(1, self.check_for_completion(file_location))  # Not like this
self.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(file_location))  # like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Stevo, thanks for the lambda tip. I think we are close, but not quite there.. Perhaps I should share the code I am using to test this with:

```
tmp, location = tempfile.mkstemp() 
print location 
frame4 = InstallerUserMessage(text = "", title = "foo")   
frame4.progress_bar(message = "bar", icon_name="logo.gif", size = 0, file_location = location) 
with closing(os.fdopen(tmp, 'w')) as tmp_handle: 
    time.sleep(5) 
    tmp_handle.write('a') 
    frame4.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(message, file_location))
    print 1 
    time.sleep(3)
    tmp_handle.write('a')
    frame4.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(message, file_location))
    print 2
    time.sleep(7)
    tmp_handle.write('a')
    frame4.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(message, file_location))
    print 3
    time.sleep(1)
    tmp_handle.write('a')
    frame4.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(message, file_location))
    print 4
    time.sleep(8)
    tmp_handle.write('a')
    frame4.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(message, file_location))
    print 5
    time.sleep(2)
    tmp_handle.write('a')
    frame4.after(1, lambda: self.check_for_completion(message, file_location))
    print 6
```

Unfortunately, what I get is the location printed out, 0 printed out from the first call to check_for_completion and then it hangs both at terminal and at progress bar, which shows full and has the Completed message.  It also seems to take a long time to paint, probably because it doesn't paint until the end?

Comment: Huh, you're giving me chunks of code that don't quite make out your problem. Perhaps you can paste it whole on pastebin or somewhere so i can debug it properly.

Comment: Hey, Stevo.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  After some thought, I've restructured the code so that the caller is responsible for checking the filesize, which simplifies the UI to a fairly standard progress bar.  I think keeping the UI agnostic to the semantics of what is actually progressing is a good thing following the notion of separation of concerns.

Thanks again.